# Mysql join Delete query issues

Tags: mysql

I have a delete query

```
     delete from Admin_course_groups ac join admin_course_details ad
 on ac.fk_c_id=ad.fk_c_id 
    where fk_g_id=1 and type='G'
```

When i run this query i got an error

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'ac inner join admin_course_details ad on ac.fk_c_id=ad.fk_c_id'
>   at line 1

My tables
**Admin_course_groups**

```
a_id | fk_c_id|fk_g_id|type
1           1   1       G
2          3     1      G
```

**admin_course_details**

```
d_id | status | fk_c_id |fk_user_id
 1     1         1         2
 2      1        3         2
```

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: The query and the error message do not add up. The query does not have aliases, while code excerpt in the error does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a target table or tables for the deletion, and you should use aliases here:

```
DELETE acg     -- or acg, acd       if you wanted to target both tables
FROM Admin_course_groups acg
INNER JOIN admin_course_details acd
    ON acg.fk_c_id = acd.fk_c_id
WHERE
    fk_g_id = 1 AND type = 'G';
```

Comment: Then follow my answer and use `DELETE acg, acd FROM ...`, that is, specify every alias whose corresponding table you also want to make a deletion target.

Comment: @Ezra I've never seen that spelling of my name before.  Nice one :-)